# Power BI, countrows based on 2 date relationships

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis

I working with recruitment data.

my main table has rows which contain each vacancy info, including open date and close date.

One of the remaining measures that I cant seem to write is returning rows based on open and close dates.

I need to write a measure that returns all the vacancies that have open date before selected date and close date after close date or is blank.

I cant seem to write this measure, my main table is connected with calendartable with both open and close dates but open date is the active relationship.

one of the many ways I tried doing it:

```
Ongoing_Diplomat_adjusted = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(DateTable),
            DateTable[WeekOfYear] < MAX(DateTable[WeekOfYear])
        ),
        [active_vacancies]
    ),
    'Needs'[open_week] < MAX(DateTable[WeekOfYear]), USERELATIONSHIP( Needs[Close Date], DateTable[Date])  // Additional condition to filter based on 'Open Date' week
)
```

or this:

```
Ongoing_Diplomat = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(DateTable[Date]),
            DateTable[Date] < MAX(DateTable[Date])
        ),
        [active_vacancies]
    )
)
```